# C# deleting a read only file

Tags: c#

Hello I'm basically trying to make a button in my application which can delete my %appdata% folder but there's a problem it keeps saying cannot delete a read only file so i decided to do some googling but the problem still continues anyways here's my latest try still didn't work any clue?

What I'm trying to delete is %appdata%/test which also has sub folders.

```
   private void ClearButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = (Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test"));
        //Get Currently Applied Access Control
        FileSecurity fileS = File.GetAccessControl(filepath);

        //Update it, Grant Current User Full Control
        SecurityIdentifier cu = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
        fileS.SetOwner(cu);
        fileS.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(cu, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        //Update the Access Control on the File
        File.SetAccessControl(filepath, fileS);

        //Delete the file
        File.Delete(filepath);
        Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: What's the result of this method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a read-only file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265896/how-do-i-delete-a-read-only-file)

Comment: @commusoft http://i.imgur.com/wdBeCH3.png

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to **take ownership** first, if you dont have

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

//Get Currently Applied Access Control
FileSecurity fileS = File.GetAccessControl(filepath);

//Update it, Grant Current User Full Control
SecurityIdentifier cu = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
fileS.SetOwner(cu);
fileS.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(cu, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

//Update the Access Control on the File
File.SetAccessControl(filepath, fileS);

File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(filePath);
```

Also, you will need to run application with administrative privileges.

For this, Right click on your project, **Add** -> **New Item** -> **Application Manifest File**

then replace this line

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with this

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
```

It will run your application with administrator privileges.

Comment: @MrRdy2Lose Edited the answer, check now

Comment: @MrRdy2Lose Edited again. Added step to add manifest file and setting administrative privileges

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/349547545/ShareX/2015/01/2015-01-05_23-54-46.png

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application with Administrative privilege .Some times C drive requires Admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when running my application in DEBUG mode.  I was able to solve it by simply setting File.IsReadOnly = false;  It then deleted with no problem.